# Rails Join Table without Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

Is it possible to create a join table without a model.
I have a model called User and Pet. I want user to have only one pet and pet to only have one owner. Very simple. However, I am trying to figure out how to create a join table

pets_users that has both users.id and pets.id in it without having to create the actual model. Is this possible? Is this a bad design?

If possible, how do I create a new entry in the pets_users table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a join table for this.

```
User has_one Pet
Pet belongs_to User
```

The pet table then would have a **user_id** column and Active Record handles the rest for you.

Comment: This would enforce a one-to-one relationship between Pets and Users, no? That is, each Pet could only belong to one User. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @skyler, that's right. The original question: "I want user to have only one pet and pet to only have one owner", so in this case no join table is needed. If, however a many-to-many relationship was required, a join table would be needed.